# Testing NHibernate mappings with PersistenceSpecification

Tags: sqlite, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nunit, integration-testing

I read a blog post today about how to test Fluent NHibernate mappings using the PersistenceSpecification class. Seemed like a very good idea, so I tried it out. However, it keeps throwing a System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException when checking an HasMany relationship. We use an SQL Lite In-memory database for the tests.

Here is what my model looks like. I snipped away some irrelevant properties, etc:

```
public class Area
{
    public virtual int AreaId{ get; set; }
    public virtual IList<AreaPolygonVertex> Vertices { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class AreaPolygonVertex
{
    public virtual Point Point { get; set; }
    public virtual int VertexNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual int AreaId { get; set; }
}

public class Point
{
    public double X {get; set;}
    public double Y {get; set;}
}
```

Here are the NHibernate mappings:

```
public class AreaMap : ClassMap<Area>
    {
        public AreaMap()
        {
            Table("VIEW_AREAS");
            Id(x => x.AreaId, "ID");
            HasMany(x => x.Vertices).KeyColumn("AREA_ID");
            ...
        }
    }

  public class AreaPolygonVertexMap : ClassMap<AreaPolygonVertex>
  {
      public AreaPolygonVertexMap()
      {
          Table("AREA_POLYGON_VERTICES");
          CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.AreaId, "AREA_ID")
                .KeyProperty(x => x.VertexNumber, "VERTEX_NO");

          Component(x => x.Point, m =>
          {
              m.Map(x => x.X, "X");
              m.Map(x => x.Y, "Y");
          });

          Map(x => x.VertexNumber, "VERTEX_NO");
          Map(x => x.AreaId, "AREA_ID");
      }
  }
```

And finally the Test:

```
[Test]
public void should_map_areas_correctly()
{
     var vertex = new AreaPolygonVertex {
          AreaId = 1, 
          Point = new Point(20, 30), 
          VertexNumber = 1
      };

      _session.Save(vertex);

      new PersistenceSpecification<Area>(_session)
            .CheckProperty(c => c.AreaId, 1)
            .CheckList(c => c.Vertices, new List<AreaPolygonVertex>{ vertex })
            .VerifyTheMappings();
 }
```

This throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, saying "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index". Not much more useful info in this exception it seems.

At first I didn't do the _session.Save(vertex) before running the verification call, but I picked up somewhere that you had to insert "child objects" into _session manually when having a HasMany relationship like this. Might not be right for my exact scenario though.

PS: The mappings and the models have been tested against a real (oracle) DB, and they should be working fine (at least for reading data). I have also tested using CheckComponentList instead of CheckList, but still the same outcome. If I remove the ".CheckList(.." line, and instead just check all the other properties, it works fine.

Hopefully someone could enlighten me if I am doing something wrong here. As mentioned, this is my first NHibernate mapping test, so be gentle =)

Answer (score 1):

- `HasMany(x => x.Vertices)` has no Cascading set which means it will not save it at all
- you mapped some columns twice, the following should be removed because they are in the compositeId already

  ```
  Map(x => x.VertexNumber, "VERTEX_NO");
  Map(x => x.AreaId, "AREA_ID");
  ```

Comment: Good tip! But I tried changing it to HasMany(x => x.Vertices).Cascade.All, and I still get the same exception..